# Error in mapping java Byte[] to actionscript ByteArray

Tags: apache-flex, mapping, arrays, graniteds

**Context - GraniteDS + JPA DataNucleus + MySQL**

The scenario is to store / retrieve an image in db.

The issue is with the retrieval FROM db. The book cover is fetched
from the db but at the flex front it shows as null.

The translation from java "Byte[]" to flex "ByteArray" is returning null.

Below are the 2 class files.

### AcrionScript class

```
[RemoteClass(alias="com.app.model.Book")]
public class Book
{
    public var id:uint;
            public var cover:ByteArray;
    }
```

### Java class

@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable{

```
@Id
private Long id;

@Lob
@Basic(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Byte[] cover = null;
```

}

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a serialization issue.

[Byte](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) with a capital B is a wrapper class that is more elaborate than the `byte` primitive object.

This is an important fact since an AMF serializer/deserializer works with introspection.
All non-primitive objects must have a specific class containing all public properties on both ends of your communication channel.

The `Byte` class is not a primitive type and therefore, it will not be recognized by default by the AMF serializer/deserializer and thus every `Byte[]` object you send from java to Flex will be automatically converted to null.

Try changing a `Byte[]` to `byte[]` and see if that works for you.

If you truely need to use Byte[], check out the granite documentation on [writing custom serialization classes](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/display/DOC/9.+Miscellaneous+Options) to be able to transport `Byte` Objects.
Keep in mind though that this will require you to write a deserializer/serializer on the Flex side as well and will probably not be a good choice when it comes to performance.

Cheers